# the display width of integer column in ms access

Tags: ms-access, integer

Is it possible to establish the display width of integer column in MS Access the same way `int(11)` works in MySQL?

or/and

How i can adapt this part of MySQL script in MS Access query:

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar_dates` (
  service_id INT(11),
  `date` VARCHAR(8),
  exception_type INT(2),
  KEY `service_id` (service_id),
  KEY `exception_type` (exception_type)
);
```

Thanks in advance for help ^_^

Comment: FYI, MySQL has deprecated integer display widths.

Comment: AFAIK, that CREATE TABLE action is setting field size and has nothing to do with display. Display can be wider or narrower than field size.

Comment: @June7 for integer field the length parameter sets the display width, not the field size in mysql. Luckily this parameter has already been deprecated as Barmar pointed out.

Comment: To format number display, use the `Format()` function in a query.

Comment: Or if your interest is the display width of a column for a table in Datasheet View, you can use VBA to set its [ColumnWidth property](https://nolongerset.com/columnwidth-deep-dive/)

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies, i really appreciate!

@Hansup i would also like to clarify KEY query from MySQL code in MS Access. since it is a synonym for INDEX, that needs to be created with CREATE INDEX, it is not possible anymore to do it in the same query with CREATE TABLE?

Comment: @atishaya Re your example, I don't know how to create those indexes in an Access CREATE TABLE statement.  Suspect you'll need either CREATE INDEX statements or to use VBA for the DAO.TableDef.CreateIndex method.

Comment: You don't need nor want to create ANY index(s) for a linked table. Linked tables = everything managed by the MySQL server. The only exception to this rule is a command to create the PK index in Access for a view when Access does not, or did not recognize the PK value being used. Anything else in terms of attempting to create some index on a linked table to MySQL should be be done, and is not required.